# How to hide/delete the rows from the gridPanel

Tags: extjs

My screen has two drop downs, and a grid. i basically do an ajax call and populate the grid based on the value from the first drop down. Now when i select the second drop down i want to hide few rows that i have populated previoulsy based on the value in the second drop down

Comment: Which version of ExtJs are you using? You are looking for a filtering feature.

Comment: You answered your own question but you didn't accept it. Are you looking for a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taskFromGrid.getStore().filter('TASK_OWNER_ID', record.get("PERSON_ID"));

i used filter and it worjke for me